# Why my mock object not working truly in xUnit test project?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, tdd, xunit

I have a Category table in my project, I used Generic repository and Unit of Work pattern in my project. It is an API. It is working when I use mock of UnitOfWork lonely but It is not working when I want to check my controller result. My controller response is 404 always. I think it is because of my mistake in setup but I don't know where it is.

`

```
[DisplayName("Category Table")]
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Priority { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? Details { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Category> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(object id);

        Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync();

        Task<T> GetEntityWithSpec(ISpecification<T> spec);

        Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListWithSpecAsync(ISpecification<T> spec);

    ...        
    }
```

```
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        private readonly FactoryContext _context;

        public GenericRepository(FactoryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(object id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetEntityWithSpec(ISpecification<T> spec)
        {
            return await ApplySpecification(spec).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListWithSpecAsync(ISpecification<T> spec)
        {
            return await ApplySpecification(spec).ToListAsync();
        }
        ...

                 private IQueryable<T> ApplySpecification(ISpecification<T> spec)
        {
            return SpecificationEvaluator<T>.GetQuery(_context.Set<T>().AsQueryable(), spec);
        }
    }
```

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, new();

        Task<int> Complete();
    }
```

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly FactoryContext _context;
        private Hashtable _repositories;

        public UnitOfWork(FactoryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<int> Complete()
        {
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }

        public IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, new()
        {
            if (_repositories == null) _repositories = new Hashtable();

            var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;

            if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                var repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>);
                var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity)), _context);

                _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
            }

            return (IGenericRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
        }


    }
```

```
public class CategoriesController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public CategoriesController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

       

        [HttpGet("getcategorybyid/{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<CategoryToReturnDto>> GetCategoryById(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var spec = new GetCategoriesWithParentsSpecification(id);

                var category = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Category>().GetEntityWithSpec(spec);

                if (category.Id == 0) return NotFound(new ApiResponse(404));

                var returnCategories = _mapper.Map<Category, CategoryToReturnDto>(category);

                return new OkObjectResult(new ApiResponse(200, "Ok", returnCategories));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, ex.Message));
            }
        }

       
    }
```

```
public class CategoriesControllerTests
    {
        private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
        private readonly Mock<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWork;

        public CategoriesControllerTests()
        {
            _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
            _unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();

        }

        

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_OK_ObjectResult_CategoryById()
        {
            //Arrange
            Category newCategory = CreateTestCategory();

            var spec = new GetCategoriesWithParentsSpecification(1);
            _unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Repository<Category>().GetEntityWithSpec(spec)).ReturnsAsync(newCategory)
                .Verifiable();

            //Act

// Here it is working and result2 has data.
            var result2 = await _unitOfWork.Object.Repository<Category>().GetEntityWithSpec(spec);

            var controller = new CategoriesController(_unitOfWork.Object, _mapper.Object);
            
            

            var result = await controller.GetCategoryById(1);

            // Assert

            result.Value?.Id.ShouldBe(newCategory.Id);
            result.Value?.Name.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(newCategory.Name);
            result.Value?.Name.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("newCategory.Name");

// My problem here. My result is NotFoundObjectResult always.
            result.Result.ShouldBeOfType<OkObjectResult>();
            
        }

        

        private Category CreateTestCategory()
        {
            return new Category()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Priority = 1,
                Name = "Test Category",
                Enabled = true,
                Details = "Testing category data"
            };
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Did you step through your test code in a debugger?

Comment: Please edit the question so that it contains a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code may be complete, but surely it isn't *minimal?*

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, I did. My repository object is null in my controller allways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spec` that you pass during the moq `setup` isn't the same as the `spec` that your repository receives inside the controller

In your test, you should change the `setup` in such a way that it checks the type of input instead and avoid passing a reference.

```
_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Repository<Category>()
                    .GetEntityWithSpec(It.IsAny<ISpecification<Category>>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(newCategory)
                .Verifiable();
```

Here we set up the moq in a way that as long as the input is `ISpecification<Category>`, it returns `newCategory`

Answer (score 1):

The specificatio didn't use truly. Your setup should be like this:

```
_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Repository<Category>()
                    .GetEntityWithSpec(It.IsAny<ISpecification<Category>>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(newCategory)
                .Verifiable();
```

Comment: Yes exactly. My problem has been fixed. Thanks a lot.